# Delete all indexes in a graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I delete all constraints and indexes from a graph without using the apoc plugin?
This obviously doesn't work:

```
FOREACH (i IN CALL db.indexes() | DROP INDEX ON i)
```

Comment: Create a new graph and copy the artifacts you want to retain from the old graph.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

There is no way to get the existing indexes and constraints using pure Cypher.

I'm not sure if this is an acceptable approach for you, but you can use the neo4j browser's `:schema` command to list all the indexes and constraints in the DB. You can then manually issue Cypher queries to drop all of them.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it directly from a cypher script

Comment: There is no way to get the existing indexes and constraints using pure Cypher.